# Spring Web Url Changes During Request Processing

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to understand the processing of a web requests with Spring Boot Web Application. I am making a request like "/test/", and it I look in the tomcat access log I see the URL as "/test/". However, if I set a breakpoint in the Filter Chain processing and look in the request object, I see the URL is /test/index.xxx even is I go as far back in the call stack as the `AccessLogValue` which is before the `ApplicationFilterChain`.

So I am guessing View Resolvers and Request Mapping Handlers are involved but I am unable to determine the code flow that modifies the request URL. Can someone point me to the code flow that is making these changes?

Thanks